# How can i use multiple buttons on one clickEvent and acces all of them

Tags: vb.net

i'm new here and I do VB.net programming.

I want to do something very specific but i don't know how to aproach it. I have one ClickEvent that i want to use for various Buttons. The problem is that i want to make that each button changes one TextBox. I don't want to do this in 4 separate ClickEvents because i would be repeating a lot of code.

Here is what i want to do:

```
Private Sub btnOpenDial1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenDial1.Click, btnOpenDial2.Click, btnOpenDial3.Click, btnOpenDial4.Click
        Dim UnitLetter As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory.Substring(0, 3)
        SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = UnitLetter
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "rtf file (*.rtf)|*.rtf"
        If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            Try
                'name is a TextBox variable that i have at the top of the program
                name = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
                If (name IsNot Nothing) Then
'              I press btnOpenDial1, this textbox changes
               txtDoc1.Text = nombre
'              I press btnOpenDial2, this textbox changes
               txtDoc2.Text = nombre
'              I press btnOpenDial3, this textbox changes
               txtDoc3.Text = nombre
'              I press btnOpenDial4, this textbox changes
               txtDoc4.Text = nombre
                End If
            Catch Ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("No se ha podido grabar el archivo: " & Ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

I hope i explained good enough. English is not my main language. I just don't want to repeat more code on my program. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use a `Dictionary(Of Control, Control)` to map a Control to another. Or, as in this case, a `Dictionary(Of Control, Action(Of String))` to map a Control to a specific Action that sets a string, since you know what Button maps to what TextBox in advance. E.g., `Dim actions As New Dictionary(Of Control, Action(of string))() actions.Add(btnOpenDial1, New Action(of string)(Sub(s) txtDoc1.Text = s))`, after that, you can call your Actions from the Buttons handler, using the same handler for all Buttons. E.g., `actions(DirectCast(sender, Button))(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

You can use one `ClickEventHandler` Method for all buttons (better of the same type as `EventArgs` may be different for different types).
On click `Event` of each button you can detect it from its name (as code shows). At this point, when you have detected the button that is clicked you can run specific code in relation with that button.

*Hope was what you wanted.*

```
Private Sub btnOpenDial1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenDial1.Click,
                                                                            btnOpenDial2.Click,
                                                                            btnOpenDial3.Click,
                                                                            btnOpenDial4.Click

    Dim pressedButton As Control = CType(sender, Control)

    Dim UnitLetter As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory.Substring(0, 3)
    SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = UnitLetter
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "rtf file (*.rtf)|*.rtf"
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        Try
            'name is a TextBox variable that i have at the top of the program
            Name = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
            If (Name IsNot Nothing) Then

                Select Case pressedButton.Name
                    Case "btnOpenDial1" : txtDoc1.Text = nombre
                    Case "btnOpenDial2" : txtDoc2.Text = nombre
                    Case "btnOpenDial3" : txtDoc3.Text = nombre
                    Case "btnOpenDial4" : txtDoc4.Text = nombre
                End Select
            End If
        Catch Ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("No se ha podido grabar el archivo: " & Ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```